# How to tackle this range lookup?

Tags: formulas

I'm using a program that is actually neither Excel nor Google Sheets (Sierra Chart), but that uses most of the same formulas to do its calculations.  However, it does not support COUNTIF, COUNTIFS, SUMIFS, etc. so I can't use those.  With that being said...

I have the following sample data:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VMsBqnu8haPS3BjhcIQfGx3yrYM714rq7mWZSmnPxNM/edit?usp=sharing

The data in columns A through C are a sample of the data I need to examine, and the results in columns E through G, are what I need to be able to determine.  I need to know in total, in how many days either condition was true, both conditions were true, or neither condition was true.  So in this example, there was 1 day with neither condition, 4 days with one condition, and 1 day with both conditions.

To be clear I don't need to know how many times a condition happened in a day, just if it happened or not.

Suggestions on how to accomplish this?  I've been at this for hours and am stumped.

Comment: This question has been bumped eight times. It's better to focus a question on using a specific web application and use the corresponding tag. Also, questions should be self-contained, considering these please describe the relevant parts of your spreadsheet, add sample data and the expected result directly into the question body.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I manage to solve this on my own.  The core need was to create a "rolling range" that would get summed if the conditions happened during a given day.  The engine behind this is:

```
=IF(
    INTDATE(A3) <> INTDATE(A4),
    IF(
        SUM(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("R",ROW() - 6, ":", "R", ROW()))) > 0,
        1,
        0
    ),0
)
```

So I evaluate the given day and make sure we are still within the same day.  If not, then it's time to sum up the number of occurrences of the condition that day, which should always be the same number of cells apart.  To generate the dynamic range, I have to CONCATENATE the parts together and use an INDIRECT to get something I can SUM.  Looks to be working nicely.  The one thing I don't love, is on the edge case where a day has fewer periods in it.  But I think that will be exceedingly rare... might be never in fact.  So for now this is doing the trick!